# Sum values depending on another field in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I have two feature classes that are both parcels. They have a field for residential type with the values being either "Residential" or "Non-Residential". They also have another field for the shape area. I am trying to write a script with arcpy that will go through the feature classes and create a row in a new table that has the name, residential type, and the total area. I am having trouble with getting the code to select and add to the table to residential types. I am also trying to do this using cursors.

This is what I have so far

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.workspace = "C://Users//dylan//Downloads//Data5//Montgomery.gdb"

tab = "SummaryTable"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polygon")

arcpy.CreateTable_management(env.workspace, tab)
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "name", "string")
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "restype", "string")
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "area", "float")
tabcur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(env.workspace + os.sep + tab, ["name","restype","area"])
```

Comment: I would use the Summary Statistics tool to do this in one line of code.

Comment: The path to your workspace is not formatted correctly. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/setting-paths-to-data.htm

Comment: @GBG , That way isn't listed in the link you sent but the way I have it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insisting on using cursors, then one approach would be like this.
Where there is a SearchCursor used to sum up the area field using a where clause to select just the residential type you require.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

def get_sum_field_value(in_table, field_name="OID@", where_clause=None):
    """Return the total value of a field in a table."""
    return sum(
        (r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, field_name, where_clause))
    )


env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:/Users/dylan/Downloads/Data5/Montgomery.gdb"

tab = "SummaryTable"
arcpy.CreateTable_management(env.workspace, tab)
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "name", "string")
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "restype", "string")
arcpy.AddField_management(tab, "area", "float")
tabcur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(env.workspace + os.sep + tab, ["name","restype","area"])

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polygon")
for fc in fcs:
    res = get_sum_field_value(fc, field_name="area", where_clause ='restype= "Residential"')
    tabcur.insertRow((fc, "Residential", res))
    non_res = get_sum_field_value(fc, field_name="area", where_clause ='restype= "Non-Residential"')
    tabcur.insertRow((fc, "Non-Residential", non_res))
del tabcur
```